# how to prevent my web page from being modified from other applications

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have one application written in C#. i am using web browser control on my application to load my web page.(web page is one module of application).

in a specific system when my application is getting launched it shows 
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. exception.

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IHTMLLocation.GetHref()
       at System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.get_Document()
       at UIApplication.frmMaps.LoadMap()
```

This exception is shown every time when trying to access JavaScript function from C# code.

by looking into Temporary internet files I observed that my JS files are converted into .htm files.

is conversion of .js file .htm file is thowing  'UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied.' error.

if yes, how can i prevent this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with other programs modifying your HTML, it's due to cross-domain/cross-origin Javascript restrictions implemented to protect websites' users (imagine if a dodgy app loaded a bank's website in a `WebBrowser` control and then the app manipulated the DOM to steal users' info?

Comment: Thanks Dai, My app loads only webpages hosted on my web server. And I have observed this issue in very few systems not all. I do use google map apis in our app. What i am unable to figure out is why cross-domain/cross-origin issue.